# Transaction issue while migrating Jboss 5.1 to WildFly 8.2

Tags: ejb, seam, wildfly

I am mygrating my application from Jboss 5.1.0 to Wild Fly 8.2. While starting the server we are fetching the data from data base and storing in application scope. This was working fine in Jboss 5.1.0 and not working on WildFly 8.2. It is showing the below warnings.

```
15:04:38,152 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff0ab6a4f7:3057cd0:55c9c01b:8 in state  RUN
15:04:38,156 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff0ab6a4f7:3057cd0:55c9c01b:8 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
15:04:38,157 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff0ab6a4f7:3057cd0:55c9c01b:8 aborting with 1 threads active!
15:04:38,158 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff0ab6a4f7:3057cd0:55c9c01b:8
```

I have double checked that my data source configuration is correct.
As part of migration I have upgraded Seam 2.2.0 to 2.3.1 and EJB 3.0 to EJB 3.1. I am suspecting that there might be an issue with upgrading Seam and EJB.

I am understanding why I am getting the above transaction, please help me if any one has solution for the above issue.

Thanks,
Sreenath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact issue was I am using hibernate 3.6.3 which is not compatible with Seam 2.3.1. This issue was resolved after migrating to Hibernate 4.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of your transaction is Timing out. There are a couple of things I would suggest that you can do.

1. In your `standalone.xml` file change the logging level to `TRACE`
   to get more details of the issue. You'll need to change the value to

   ```
   <logger category="com.arjuna">
      <level name="TRACE"/>
   </logger>
   ```
2. You can increase the Timeout value to something higher, the default value is 300. For changing the time out

   - Login To JBoss Management Console (localhost:9990 by default)
   - Go To Configuration >  container > Timeout
   - Change the `Default Timeout` value to something higher.

You can look into [this thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/261828?start=0&tstart=0) for some help.

Comment: Hey Shiva, I already tried the above ways, after changing the time out it is throwing the above warnings after the given time and i didn't find any issue in Logger trace.

Comment: Hey Shiva, Unfortunately that thread was created by me :), I posted the same in stack overflow :).